# how to upload an excel sheet and compare it with data in database?

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet

Can someone figure out the logic on how to upload an excel sheet into a web server and to compare it with already existing data.

Say I have some data in my database which looks similar to an excel sheet arrangement. Now i need to upload an excel sheet and compare it with DB and to do some kind of sorting and all. And finally I need to import the final result as an excel and download it. So at the same time i need to remove the uploaded file also.

NB: i dont need the code.. i need someone to explain me the concept so that i can try coding it myself

Answer (score 0):

**Check this :**

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post>
<input type="file" name="txtFile" id="eskal"  /></br>
<input type="submit" name="Import" value="Update Database" /> </b>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
$host="localhost"; // Host name.
$db_user="root";
$db_password="";
$db='test'; // Database name.
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());

echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
//echo $ext=substr($filename,strrpos($filename,"."),(strlen($filename)-strrpos($filename,".")));


 if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
 {

  $file = fopen($filename, "r");
  while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
  {
   // You can compare your data inside this while loop as well as above the while loop.
   print_r($emapData);
   $sql = "INSERT into import(name,address,email,password) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]')";
   mysql_query($sql);
 }
         fclose($file);
         echo "CSV File has been successfully Imported";
 }
 else
 echo "Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File";

}
?>
```

Comment: i dont need the code.. i need someone to explain me the concept so that i can try coding it myself